# Juntar registros iguais em uma tabela HTML

Tags: php, html

Possuo uma tabela que me retornam vários registros.

***Cógido Tabela:***

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>N° Prog</th>
          <th>Data Opr</th>
          <th>Origem</th>
          <th>Destino</th>
          <th>Remetente</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
          <th>Peso Total</th>
          <th>Destinatário</th>
          <th>Previsão de Chegada</th>
          <th>Veículo</th>
          <th>Placa</th>
          <th>Motorista</th>
          <th>Observação</th>
          <th>St</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($controller->ListaTudo($objProg) as $objProg){ ?>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getprog(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getdataopr(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getorig(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getdest(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getremetente(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getpeso(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getpesottl(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getdestinatario(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getprev(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getcarreta(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getobs(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $objProg->getst1(); ?></td>
       </tr>
   <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que quando o N° Prog (no caso os três números 74 da imagem) forem iguais, de tipo um `rowspan` na `td`, que fique só um "74" mas o resto continue sendo 3 linhas. Porém nem sempre serão 3 registros iguais, podem ser mais ou somente um.

Comment: Crie uma lógica antes, contando os valores iguais e guarde como rowspan, antes de montar o `foreach`.
Após, faça a montagem trazendo esse resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda das outras respostas, encontrei uma solução:

Do jeito que está ai, você precisa varrer os valores antes de dar o `echo` com outro looping.

Veja:

**EDITADA**

```
        <?php 
     echo "<td>";
    // acredito que o method ListaTudo retorna um array certo? =D
    // então coloquei na variável prog
    $prog = $controller->ListaTudo($objProg);

    // quantidade listada
    $quantProg = count($prog);

    // arrays que iremos usar no looping for
    $valor = array(); // este array contem o valor da variavel
    $rowArray = array(); // este array vamos registrar os rows
    $row = 1; // este array quantas x ele se repete

    // vamos varrer os valores antes do foreach

    for($x = 0; $x <= $quantProg; $x++){

        if($x < $quantProg){

            // insere valor
            $valor[$x] = $prog[$x] -> getprog();

        }

        if($x > 0) {

            $y = $x -1;

            if(isset($valor[$x]) &&  $valor[$x] == $valor[$y]){

                $row++;

            } else {

                if($x < $quantProg){

                    $w = $x - $row;

                } else {

                    $w = $quantProg - 1;

                }

                echo "<td rowspan='".$row."'>".$valor[$w]."</td>";

                foreach ($prog as $objProg){ 

                    echo "<td>".$objProg->getdataopr()."</td>
                    <td>".$objProg->getorig()."</td>
                    ... </tr>"; 
                    // insira todas as variáveis do foreach...

                }

                $row = 1;

            }

        }


    }

    ?>
```

Claro que podem haver erros pois eu não fiz o teste. Mas a lógica seria isso.

Eu fiz dessa forma mas o ideal é ter uma função que retorna isso para você.

Comment: Entendi só me retornou este erro `Undefined offset: -1` no `if($quantRow[$x] == $quantRow[$y]){`

Comment: tenta agora @Kevin.F ! Fiz o contrário. Coloquei o `foreach` dentro do `for`. Isso permitiu melhorar a unificação. Criei uns arrays para fazer teste e funcionou

Answer (score 2):

a propriedade do `<html>` que você procura é o "rowspan" ela é ligada ao  `<td>`, é uma tag que acumula a quantidade de linhas que repetem de um mesmo valor, no seu caso 3, então na primeira linha `<tr>` acumula a quantidade total de repetições por linha `<td rowspan="3">74</td>` em uma mesma coluna e nas próximas linhas não pode exibir esse valor (ou o `<td>`):

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>N° Prog</th>
          <th>Data Opr</th>
          <th>Origem</th>
          <th>Destino</th>
          <th>Remetente</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
          <th>Peso Total</th>
          <th>Destinatário</th>
          <th>Previsão de Chegada</th>
          <th>Veículo</th>
          <th>Placa</th>
          <th>Motorista</th>
          <th>Observação</th>
          <th>St</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">74</td>
        <td>12/07/2016</td>
        <td>BTO</td>
        <td>SPO</td>
        <td>MOVEIS K1</td>
        <td>13300.00</td>
        <td>23400.00</td>
        <td>SID LAR</td>
        <td>19/07/2016</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ISW-5946</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/07/2016</td>
        <td>BTO</td>
        <td>SPO</td>
        <td>UNICASA</td>
        <td>4100.00</td>
        <td>23400.00</td>
        <td>SID LAR</td>
        <td>19/07/2016</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ISW-5946</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/07/2016</td>
        <td>BTO</td>
        <td>SPO</td>
        <td>UNICASA</td>
        <td>600.00</td>
        <td>23400.00</td>
        <td>SID LAR</td>
        <td>19/07/2016</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ISW-5946</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```